# How to split adifferent length number into digits in R

Tags: r, database, split

I have a data frame that contains a numerical ID variable for each individual observation. However, not all numbers are the same length. I want to split the original value and include missing values where there are no numbers.

Example:

```
ID Var              
  1901                 
501901
```

I need it to look this way:

```
ID1    ID2     ID3      ID4      ID5      ID6    
                1        9        0        1            
5      0        1        9        0        1
```

I have tried using

```
cbind(read.fwf(file = textConnection(as.character(df[,1])), widths = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2), 
               colClasses = "character", col.names = c("ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID5", "ID6", "ID7")))
```

but it only considers variables that contain numbers of full length.

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method using base R functions:

```
# example data
id <- c(14, 1901, 1237, 990, 501901)

charList <- strsplit(sprintf(paste0("%", max(nchar(id)), ".0f"), id), split="")

# put into data.frame
myData <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, charList))
myData
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1              1  4
2        1  9  0  1
3        1  2  3  7
4           9  9  0
5  5  0  1  9  0  1
```

As @richard-scriven mentions, this produces factor variables, which typically are only useful in particular situations. To perform a conversion to integers, you could do the following:

```
myData[] <- lapply(myData, function(i) as.integer(as.character(i)))
```

Comment: Beware that this results in factor columns

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
a <- c(1901, 501901)
b <- as.character(a)
d <- str_pad(b, 6, pad = " ")
out <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(d, "")))
out[out == " "] <- NA
```